# The event works in my React project, but the page stays the same. (with Spring Boot)

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, axios

I've tried many alternative ways for a long time, but I haven't reached a completely working result. There are changes in Spring Boot and database, but they are not reflected in my React page. But if I refresh the page, everything I've done before comes to my page properly, but I want it to be updated instantly. I will be glad if you help.

Codes of the relevant page :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import VisibilityIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Visibility";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";
import EditIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Edit";
import Switch from "@material-ui/core/Switch";
import {
  getApps,
  updateStopRisk,
  countLiveCountry,
  updateAppShow,
  deleteApp,
} from "../api/apiCalls";
import Modal from "./Modal";

const ManagementList = (props) => {
  const [apps, setApps] = useState([]);
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);
  const [currentApp, setCurrentApp] = useState("");
  const [appID, setAppID] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { data: appsResponse } = await getApps();
      console.log(appsResponse);
      const countLiveCountries = await fetchLiveCountriesForApps(appsResponse);
      setApps(
        appsResponse.map((app, idx) => ({
          ...app,
          countLiveCountry: countLiveCountries[idx],
        }))
      );
    })();
  }, []);

  const fetchLiveCountriesForApps = async (appwLive) => {
    const countLiveCountries = await Promise.all(
      appwLive.map((app) => countLiveCountry(app.appID))
    );
    return countLiveCountries.map(({ data: liveCountries }) => liveCountries);
  };

  const removeApp = async () => {
    await deleteApp(appID);
    setModalVisible(false);
  };

  const onClickCancel = () => {
    setModalVisible(false);
  };

  const changeCheck = (iddd) => {
    updateStopRisk(iddd);

  };
  const changeTrack = (id) => {
    updateAppShow(id);

  };

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="container"
        style={{ marginTop: 20, fontFamily: "tahoma" }}
      >
        <h2 style={{ float: "left", font: "bold" }}>Management</h2>
        <div style={{ float: "right" }}>
          <Link className="btn btn-danger btn-sm" to="/management/newapp">
            Add New App
          </Link>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm ml-3">
            Plant Management
          </button>
        </div>
        <table className="text-center table table-sm table table-striped table table-bordered">
          <tr style={{ background: "#cccccc" }}>
            <th scope="col">Application Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Business Area</th>
            <th scope="col">Live Plants</th>
            <th scope="col">Line Stop Risk</th>
            <th scope="col">
              Actions<br></br>
              <h7 className="col-2">View</h7>
              <h7 className="col-2">Edit</h7>
              <h7 className="col-2">Delete</h7>
              <h7 className="col-2">Track</h7>{" "}
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tbody>
            {apps &&
              apps.map((app) => (
                <tr key={app.appID}>
                  <td>{app.appFullName}dsf</td>
                  <td>{app.businessArea.businessareaName}</td>
                  <td>{app.countLiveCountry}</td>
                  <td>
                    <input
                      checked={app.appStopRisk}
                      onClick={() => changeCheck(app.appID)}
                      id="appStopRisk"
                      type="checkbox"
                      class="form-control"
                    />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <Link
                      className="btn btn-manage-link btn-sm col-2"
                      to={`/management/${app.appID}`}
                    >
                      <VisibilityIcon></VisibilityIcon>
                    </Link>
                    <Link
                      to={`/management/edit/${app.appID}`}
                      className="btn btn-manage-link btn-sm col-2"
                    >
                      <EditIcon></EditIcon>
                    </Link>
                    <button
                      onClick={() => {
                        setModalVisible(true);
                        setCurrentApp(app.appName);
                        setAppID(app.appID);
                      }}
                      className="btn btn-manage-link btn-sm col-2"
                    >
                      <DeleteIcon></DeleteIcon>
                    </button>
                    <Switch
                      onClick={() => changeTrack(app.appID)}
                      checked={app.appShow}
                      className="col-3"
                    ></Switch>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <Modal
          message={
            <div>
              <div>
                <strong>{currentApp}</strong>
              </div>
            </div>
          }
          onClickCancel={onClickCancel}
          onClickOk={removeApp}
          appID={appID}
          visible={modalVisible}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default ManagementList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to retrive the data again after you sent the action to your backend application.

You are fetching the data only when your page is loaded, this data wont change automaticaly when you send an action to the backend to remove or update something.

If you want to change the page data when performs an action, regardless your API response, you have to edit the current object, on your case, calling setApps() with the new data. But this approach could generate some inconsistenses if you don't garantee that your API really did their job.

UPDATE:

Implementation

Transform your fetch routine into a useCallback and use it on your useEffect to fetch data when starts the page.

```
const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    const { data: appsResponse } = await getApps();
    const countLiveCountries = await fetchLiveCountriesForApps(appsResponse);
    setApps(
        appsResponse.map((app, idx) => ({
            ...app,
            countLiveCountry: countLiveCountries[idx]
        }))
    );
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
}, [fetchData]);
```

Then, call the fetchData after your actions:

```
const removeApp = async () => {
    await deleteApp(appID);
    setModalVisible(false);
    fetchData();
};

const onClickCancel = () => {
    setModalVisible(false);
};

const changeCheck = async (iddd) => {
    await updateStopRisk(iddd);
    fetchData();
};
const changeTrack = async (id) => {
    await updateAppShow(id);
    fetchData();
};
```

Here a live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/so-67142713-fiv3i?file=/src/ManagementList.jsx

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What you said is quite logical, but I have not implemented it properly. I would be glad if there is any sample or code you can show.

Comment: Awesome and incredible, I am thankful to you. You taught me a lot and saved my days. Thank you so much. Best regards !